# Double return confirm with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Maybe the question is silly,but I'm learning javascript and don't understand why when I have a following code:

```
confirm("ready to go");
confirm("ready for learn");
```

the console shows me only the last response (true/false) and not both responses.

Comment: The console _always_ shows the result of the last statement. If you want both results, you need to save the results somehow.

Comment: or manually log them `console.log(...valuesToLog)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because js is [well, almost] an applicative language, and the semicolon causes those two expressions to be evaluated one after another, and you only see the value of the last one.

If you want to catch both answers, you can assign them to variables, e.g.

```
var ans1 = confirm("ready to go");
var ans2 = confirm("ready for learn");
```

You also could use a list, like this:

```
[confirm("ready to go"), confirm("ready for learn")]
```

and probably you'd like to assign it to a variable as well...

Good luck and happy learning!

Answer (score 3):

You have to store it's result somewhere, otherwise it will always give you last result.

```
var result1 = confirm("ready to go");
var result2 = confirm("ready for learn");
console.log(result1 + '   ' + result2);
```

Comment: Even better: `console.log(result1, result2);` or `console.log(confirm("ready to go"), confirm("ready for learn"));`.

Comment: Well yes, depending what he wants

Comment: for now its just for learning purposes. but, @Xufox has righ, better if i want to watch what i do. thnks. :)